# Relation between Electric Potential and Electric Field Intensity

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, potential

Suppose we have been given a curve y = V(x) where V(x) represents the Electric Potential at x. Now if for a range the curve is a horizontal straight line, can we say that the Electric field intensity in that range will be equal to 0 because $dV = \vec{E}\cdot \vec{dr}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation you're looking for is:

$$\vec{E}=-\vec{\nabla}V$$

If $V$ depends on $x$ only, the gradient becomes:

$$\vec{E}=-V'(x)\vec{e}_x$$

so $\vec{E}$ is indeed zero in that interval.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you called $y$ the function $V(x)$ which makes my answer awkward.

We live in a three dimensional world, with coordinates, say $x,z,w$ since I cannot use $y$...

As you wrote $dV = \vec{E}\cdot \vec{dr}$

Since **along $x$**, one does have $dV=0$ you know that the cdot product is indeed zero. This proves that the component of $\vec{E}$ **along $x$** is zero.

It does **not** prove that the electric field is zero, since the components of $\vec{E}$ along the two other directions $z$ and $w$ need not vanish.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is to say that the component of the electric field in the $x$-direction is zero but there may be an electric field perpendicular to the $x$-direction ($y$ and $z$ directions).

Think of the region between a pair of charged parallel plates which make up a capacitor.

Moving a charge in a direction parallel to the plates requires no work to be done (equipotential) but work is done moving charge in a direction perpendicular to the plates.